# ssh on CentOS6 no longer works with GitHub

Tags: git, ssh, centos6

Yesterday git pull/push on a CentOS6 box stopped working because of GitHub enforcing a later version of ssh than the CentOS6 one (OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013).

Fair enough, this is an obsolete OS / version of ssh, I get that, but I have a project that still requires builds on CentOS6.

Can a more recent version be built from source or are there dependencies that make it impossible? Using devtoolset-2 version of gcc (4.8.2).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use an HTTPS remote instead of an SSH remote.  CentOS 6 supports TLS 1.2, which should be sufficient to connect to GitHub.  You will have to use a personal access token, however, which means you'll probably need to copy and paste the token from a secured location like your password manager.  You could use the `cache` credential helper to cache the token for a period of time if you'd like.

You could try building a newer version of OpenSSH, but you're really better off upgrading your system, since CentOS 6 has no security support.  Running systems without security updates not only puts your system at risk of compromise, but it can be used as part of a botnet as well, making it a general hazard to the Internet.  For example, several unpatched bugs in OpenSSL could result in security problems that could well affect your new version of OpenSSH as well as TLS connections using HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate that - I thought hpps access to GitHub closed last year. The CentOS6 machine is a VM, which only gets powered up to do a git pull & software build, so even if compromised could be deleted and rebuilt fairly quickly.

Comment: Brilliant! I set up a github Personal Access Token (the required minimum scopes of 'repo', 'workflow' and 'admin:org'. The downloaded the github CLI 'gh' from github.com/cli, ran that, entered the PAT. All now working fine.